6 person team. 3 pple play at a time. Need a schedule where we rotate and everyone gets to play with the other 5 as equally as possible. 27or29 games
I am on a 6 person team. 3 people on the team play a game against another team of 3. I need a schedule where we rotate every game and everyone gets to play with the other 5 players on our team as equally as possible. This is a weekly game, so I wouldn't want a player off for more than 2 weeks. Playing 2 weeks in a row is fine, but not 3 weeks in a row. Schedule this year is 27 games. Next year possible 29. If there is a pattern that solves this, or a pattern that repeats itself within the 27 games, that would be great!
Thank you.

There are $~\displaystyle \frac{\binom{6}{3}}{2} = \binom{5}{2} = 10~$ different ways of deciding who gets paired with Player-1.  However, based on your constraints, that is only the first step in attacking your posted question.

Your posted question confuses me.  If, each week, $~3~$ people play against the other $~3~$ people, then each person is playing every week.  However, you added the constraint that (for example) no one is off for more than 2 weeks in a row.  However, as I understand the posting none of the $~6~$ people ever get a week off.  What am I missing?

Thank you for responding.

I am looking for a playing rotation schedule between the 6 guys on the team when only 3 play at a time. I would like all 6 players to play with the other 5 an equal amount of time as possible.  We play once a week, (3 players at a time), for 29 weeks. No player should play more than 2 weeks in a row, or not play more than 2 weeks in a row. Example- week 1, players 123, week 2 players 456, week 3 players 146, week 4 players 236, etc... I am an older gentleman and I was hoping there was a schedule solution for this. Hoping for a solution. Thank you all very much.

Interesting comment, which contradicts your posted question: "3 people on the team play a game against another team of 3."

I am unsure that I am interpreting the question correctly.
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{3} = 20~$ ways of selecting the $~3~$ people out of $~6.~$  Of these $~20~$ ways, exactly $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{2} = 10~$ ways involve Player-1.
Consider the following tableau:
Week  Three Chosen    Three Remaining
  1   1, 2, 3         4, 5, 6
  3   1, 2, 4         3, 5, 6
  5   1, 2, 5         3, 4, 6
  7   1, 2, 6         3, 4, 5
  9   1, 3, 4         2, 5, 6

 11   1, 3, 5         2, 4, 6
 13   1, 3, 6         2, 4, 5
 15   1, 4, 5         2, 3, 6
 17   1, 4, 6         2, 3, 5
 19   1, 5, 6         2, 3, 4

In the above tableau, Player-1 plays in the odd numbered weeks.  In the even numbered week $~2k,~$ those three players who did not participate in week $~(2k-1)~$ play.
So, in week $~(2k-1)~$ and week $~2k~$ combined, all $~6~$ players participate, in two groups of $~3.~$  Therefore, no player can possibly play 3 weeks in a row, or skip 3 weeks in a row.
From week 21 on, you simply rinse and repeat, starting again with the week 1 schedule.

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
See also the comments of jonnybolton16, immediately following my answer.  These comments makes sense to me, and I think they should be a part of my answer.
So, I am also inserting these comments here.

You should add that since the pattern repeats after 20 matches and a season isn't an integer multiple of 20, in order to keep an even spread of everyone playing with everyone else, each new season should continue where the last left off, instead of starting again from week 1. So the second season would start with week 8


...when considering the impact on actual people, maybe it's not ideal to have Player-1 playing literally every-other week, whereas for example Player-4 has a much greater variability in consecutive weekes on/off. Perhaps the order needs to be randomised? And maybe even a new random order needs to be generated everytime the cycle begins again?


...randomise the order of the pairs (1,2), (3,4), (5,6) etc, and for each pair also randomise the order (inside) of the pair


Nice answer. You should add that since the pattern repeats after 20 matches and a season isn't an integer multiple of 20, in order to keep an even spread of everyone playing with everyone else, each new season should continue where the last left off, instead of starting again from week 1. So the second season would start with week 8

@jonnybolton16 +1 : nice comment.  See the Addendum at the end of my answer.

Thanks! Also, while your answer is nice and systematic, when considering the impact on actual people, maybe it's not ideal to have Player-1 playing literally every-other week, whereas for example Player-4 has a much greater variability in consecutive weekes on/off. Perhaps the order needs to be randomised? And maybe even a new random order needs to be generated everytime the cycle begins again?

To be more precise - randomise the order of the pairs (1,2), (3,4), (5,6) etc, and for each pair also randomise the order within the pair.

+1 : also to your second comment, which I have also excerpted into my answer's Addendum.

Thank you all for your solutions. Yes, it is a balanced schedule after 20 weeks. For the remaining 8 to 10 weeks, I will look at how to tweak the schedule, so that all 6 of us play an equal amount of times as possible with each other. Thank you all again!
